# return result of recursively executed query using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am new with codegniter.
I have used the following code to execute  function recursively.

In the first call i pass reply_id then in the function  i have used query to select id those having
parent_id = reply_id then in the foreach i do the same process for all selected ids.

Now i want to return the combine array for all recursion.because for each id query is executed and get new result each time.
how can i do that??

```
$resultq3 = $this->showreply($reply_id); //first call to function

<?php
    public function showreply( $reply_id ) {
       $q1 =$this->db->select('*')
                 ->from('forum_reply AS fr')
                 ->where('fr.parent_id',$reply_id)
                 ->order_by('fr.id ')->get();;

       foreach( $q1->result_array() as $row4 ) {
          $id = $row4['id'];  
          $parent_id = $row4['parent_id'];
          if( $parent_id !=0 ) {  
              $this->showreply( $id );
          }
       }
       return  $result; //here want to return result
    }
 ?>
```

Edited code:

```
$resultq3 = $this->showreply($reply_id); //first call to function

    <?php
        public function showreply( $reply_id ) {
           $q1 =$this->db->select('*')
                     ->from('forum_reply AS fr')
                     ->where('fr.parent_id',$reply_id)
                     ->order_by('fr.id ')->get();;

           foreach( $q1->result_array() as $row4 ) {

              $arr1 = $q1->result_array();
              $arr = array_merge($arr, $arr1);

              $id = $row4['id'];  
              $parent_id = $row4['parent_id'];
              if(!empty($arr1)) {  
                  $this->showreply( $id );
              }
           }
           return $arr;
        }
     ?>
```

Comment: @MRSrinivas:how can i find nested id without recursion??

Comment: What is the exact format that you need the data in when all the recursion is complete? This is a common scenario for recursion (so I disagree with MR Srinivas), but it's difficult to see exactly what data you need in the end. Is it a list of ID's? How do you want to know if an ID has children?

Comment: @cryode:I need to store result of each $q1 in array and return it to $resultq3.so i can use $resultq3 in view to display result.

Comment: Looking more closely at your function, it seems odd. First, you're basing your query on the `parent_id` field, but then you check the results to see if `parent_id` is empty (which it won't be -- they'll all have the same parent). If they *aren't* empty, you're using the ID as the parent for your recursive check. Maybe you should better explain your situation, because something isn't right to me.

Comment: Check my edited code. if you want records of `$parent_id !=0` then place `array_push($id, $row4);` inside the `if` block.

Comment: @Cryode:See my Edited code in this i used array merge,Now is i am doing correct array merge and how i return this result in $resultq3.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function showreply($parent_id = 0)
{
    $q1 = $this->db->select('*')
                    ->from('forum_reply AS fr')
                    ->where('fr.parent_id', $parent_id)
                    ->order_by('fr.id ')->get();

    $arr = array();
    foreach ($q1->result_array() as $row4)
    {
        $arr1 = $row4;

        $id = $row4['id'];
        $parent_id = $row4['parent_id'];
        $arr1['child'] = $this->showreply($id);
        $arr[]=$arr1;
    }

    return $arr; //here want to return result
}
```